# Sum of closed subspaces of a Hilbert space is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $M, N ⊂ H$ ($H$ Hilbert), be two closed linear subspaces.
Assume that $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$ $∀u ∈ M$, $∀v ∈ N$. Prove that $M + N$ is closed.

Take a sequence $(g_n)\in M+N$ such that $g_n\to x\in H$.

Then for any $n\geq 1$, $\exists v_n\in N, u_n\in M$ such that $g_n=v_n+u_n$. This implies that the sequences $(v_n)$ and $(u_n)$ converge singularly to the elements $v,u\in H$, and by closeness $v\in N$ and $u\in M$.

By uniqueness of the limit it must hold $x=u+v$ which implies $x\in N+M$.

I did not use any property of orthogonality so I guess this reasoning is wrong. Why? And how should I use orthogonality?

Comment: You'll need to actually prove that $(u_n)$, $(v_n)$ converge to a limit. Getting a bound on $u_n,v_n$ norms in terms of $g_n$'s norm will require orthogonality.

Comment: @JHance I have that by orthogonality: $||g_n||^2=||u_n||^2+||v_n||^2$, therefore $||u_n||\leq ||g_n||$ and $||v_n||\leq ||g_n||$. How does this imply converge to a limit?

Comment: Hint: this theorem wouldn't work in a general inner product space. You need completeness.

Comment: Your proof is correct. The orthogonality is not needed, the same holds if the angle between $M$ and $N$ is positive, i.e., if $\inf\{\frac{|\langle u,v\rangle|}{\| u\| \| v\|}; 0\ne u\in M0\ne v\in N\}>0$.

Comment: @JHance Completeness means that every Cauchy sequence converges. What I would say is that since $(g_n)$ converges than it's Cauchy, therefore $(v_n)$ and $(u_n)$ are Cauchy and must converge. But I am not sure that $(g_n)$ being Cauchy implies $(u_n),\ (v_n)$ are Cauchy.

Comment: Actually, the sum of closed subspaces $M$ and $N$ in a Hilbert space, such that the intersection $M\cap N$ is trivial, is closed if and only if the angle between the subspaces is positive.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435588/direct-sum-of-orthogonal-subspaces).

Comment: @JankoBracic thank you! But [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space) the guy is saying that if is $H$ a Banach space, then, the direct sum of two closed subspace is not necessarily closed.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you very much! That is the link I was missing.

Comment: @Filippo In general Banach spaces the situation is different. In a Hilbert space we have inner product and this helps in defining the angle between two closed subspaces (if their intersection is trivial, then the definition is above - for nontrivial intersection we have to eliminate vectors which are in both subspaces).

Comment: One should also be careful what "direct sum" sum means: in context of Hilbert spaces we usually think "orthogonal direct sum". But if we use the Banach space terminology, then also in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces there exist closed subspaces such that their "direct sum" is not closed (the angle between subspaces must be zero).

Comment: would you know how to help me with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106827/orthogonal-projection-on-subspace)?

Comment: Filippo: Sorry but I prefer to wait that you post [your own answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112595) and accept it one minute later.

Comment: Brezis exercise 5.17 (for future readers coming from this reference).

Answer (score 7):

Without orthogonality this is false: an example is [given by Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135547).

Orthogonality implies that $\|u+v\|^2 = \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$ for $u\in M$, $v\in N$. Thus, if a sequence $(u_n+v_n)$ converges, the inequalities such as
$$\|u_n-u_m\|\le \|(u_n+v_n)-(u_m+v_m)\|$$
imply convergence of both $u_n$ and $v_n$. So, $u_n\to u\in M$ and $v_n\to v\in N$, which implies $\lim(u_n+v_n  ) = u+v\in M+N$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a proof without using limits.

The following fact can be found in any book of Functional Analysis, its proof is easy:

> **Fact 1:** Let $G$ be a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, then $G^{\bot \bot}=\overline{G}$.

Therefore, we have to show that $(M+N)^{\bot\bot}\subseteq M+N$. In fact, let $x\in (M+N)^{\bot\bot}$, then 
$$\left\langle x,y \right\rangle =0 \qquad \forall y\in (M+N)^{\bot}. \tag{I}$$

Another fact that is easy to show is the following:

> **Fact 2:** $(M+N)^{\bot}=M^{\bot}\cap N^{\bot}.$

Since $M$ is closed then $H=M\oplus M^{\bot}$, then there exists $m\in M$ and $m^{\bot}\in M^{\bot}$ such that $x=m+m^{\bot}$.

But we know that $M\bot N$ then $N\subset M^{\bot}$, then **we have to show that $m^{\bot} \in N$**.

In fact, note that if $m^{\bot}=0$ then we finished, there would be nothing to show. So,  we suppose that $m^{\bot} \notin N$ with $m^{\bot}\neq 0$, then since $N$ is closed we have $H=N\oplus N^{\bot}$, so $m^{\bot}\in N^{\bot}$. Therefore, $m^{\bot}\in M^{\bot}\cap N^{\bot}$, then by **Fact 2** we have that $m^{\bot}\in (M+N)^{\bot}$. Therefore, by **Fact 1** we have 
$$0=\left\langle x,m^{\bot} \right\rangle =\left\langle m+m^{\bot},m^{\bot} \right\rangle=\left\langle m^{\bot},m^{\bot} \right\rangle=\left\|m^{ \bot}\right\|^{2}.$$
Then $m^{\bot}=0$, what contradicts $m^{\bot}\neq 0$.

Comment: This proof is incomplete. Just because $m^\perp\notin N$ and $H=N\oplus N^\perp$ does not mean $m^\perp\in N^\perp$...